# Firebase in production

Tags: php, laravel, firebase

I use firebase [php-sdk for laravel](https://github.com/kreait/laravel-firebase). It works nice on my test site, on localhost, but on prod with same credentials doesn't. Example: I validate same fcm token `Firebase::messaging()->validateRegistrationTokens('fLaGUygupk9NkwcHkHyrsM:APA91bH7Y0QgNQ4XcHGWA8OC8i-FqBQ2nAKnv0P-BQhJp_kFPMsGOSTM8k8XJQawYCu9Anh24Yw5fN1aJoV8ATugdW-Epn-Lqow_39IahaXVL9Hhpqlkk_i1PHjgn0yRHOZPq6URI_7D')` and on test site I have this

```
Array
(
    [valid] => Array
        (
            [0] => fLaGUygupk9NkwcHkHyrsM:APA91bH7Y0QgNQ4XcHGWA8OC8i-FqBQ2nAKnv0P-BQhJp_kFPMsGOSTM8k8XJQawYCu9Anh24Yw5fN1aJoV8ATugdW-Epn-Lqow_39IahaXVL9Hhpqlkk_i1PHjgn0yRHOZPq6URI_7D
        )

    [unknown] => Array
        (
        )

    [invalid] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

but on prod - this

```
Array
(
    [valid] => Array
        (
        )

    [unknown] => Array
        (
        )

    [invalid] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

I create new key, new tokens but result is the same

Comment: From existing questions I've seen the recent days - and I've only read some - there is no requirement at all that only [tag:laravel] works on localhost it must work on a remote host. Most often when it works on localhost but not on the remote host, there was the biggest chance that users could solve their issue by contacting their hosting support. Have you tried that? Also please see [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746) and provide and consider to [edit] for a [mre], see [tour] and [help].

Comment: The problem is with auth. I have Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. You need to disable cache_store in firebase config.

Comment: Share a bit more, like how you realized that and where/how that is done for example. And congratulations to your first complete Q&A!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).